# Using compression with C# webservice client in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webservice-client

I'm invoking a webservice using C# and Visual Studio 2010. VS2010 takes care of generating the client proxy code when I provide the link to the WSDL. Is there a way to configure the client code to set the 'Accept-Encoding' header to (gzip, deflate) and handle compressed responses from the server? If not, how do I write custom code to handle this?

Comment: You cannot invoke a webservice with using VS2010. VS2010 is an IDE, If you are talking about a tool like Wcf Test Client which is a  part of VS2010, I understand that... Anyway, I think you can't compress the Accept-Encoding header with gzip lib, or something else..

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Compression-Example-9ffab49c). It is an article on using compression with a WCF service. I am making the assumption (possibly incorrect) that you have control of both the service and the client. If this is somebody else's service, you can't perform a Harry Potter and make it magically compress, unless they have coded that possibility. If you are in complete control of both ends, you can make the magic happen. ;-)