# Compress a HttpWebRequest using gzip

Tags: c#, soap, gzip, soap-client, irs

I am developing a `.NET 4.0` Console Application to serve as a `SOAP Web Service` client which will send data (POST) through to a third-party.  I have no control over the web service on the server-side.  The third-party did provide `WSDL's` to use, and I was able to import them and use them with reasonable success.  However, there is a requirement to compress the request message using `gzip`, and I could not for the life of me figure out how to do that using the proxy services.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787923/using-compression-with-c-sharp-webservice-client-in-visual-studio-2010?lq=1) here on SO, led me to believe that without having control over both the client and server code, the request is unable to be compressed.  As a result of this finding, I wrote the code in my application to manually create the `SOAP XML` in a `XDocument` object; then, populated the values from the  `WSDL` proxy class objects which I had previously coded my client application to use.

The first requirement for this client, is to send the message compressed via `gzip`.  After some research, I have seen answers as simple as just adding the `HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate"` to the request header.  Unfortunately, doing that that didn't appear to work.

Currently, the certificate which I am retrieving is not the real certificate.  I am trying to make the code as sound as I can before deploying to a test environment to do the actual service testing.

1. Is there a way to compress the request via the proxy call (`wsdl`)?
2. Is there something I am missing in order to properly compress the `HttpWebRequest`?
3. Might there be something else going wrong which would result in the error message to be returned?
   *I would expect a different message pertaining to authentication being invalid if the request itself was OK*.
4. Is there a way the compression can be done through the `app.config`?

The next set of requirements I'm a little confused on how to handle/what to do.  Under the assumption that what I have set the `ContentType` of the request to, how (and what) do I add in order to add the `content-transfer-encoding` piece to the request?  If the `ContentType` is incorrect, how should I add this information as well?

> The content type for the SOAP Evenlope with MTOM encoded attachment must be "application/xop+xml" and the content-transfer-encoding must be 8-bit.

I've gone through a few iterations of the code below, however, I believe the relevant snippets are the code at its simplest form.  Please let me know if there is other information that would be helpful.

**Method to create the HttpWebRequest:**

```
private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(SoapAction action)
{
    string url = GetUrlAddress(action);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action.ToString());
    request.ContentType = "application/xop+xml";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.ClientCertificates.Add(/* Retrieve X509Certificate Object*/);

    return request;
}
```

**Code to Send Request:**

```
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    soapXml.Save(stream);
}
```

**Code to retrieve the Response:**
*This is how I am retrieving the error message that is occurring*

```
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response, Encoding.Default))
        {
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, response.Headers.ToString());
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message being Received:**

> The request message must be sent using HTTP compression (RFC 1952 - GZIP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was able to solve the compression error message by adding the following to the `HttpWebRequest` method:

```
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip");
```

**Updated Method to create the HttpWebRequest:**

```
private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(SoapAction action)
{
    string url = GetUrlAddress(action);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip"); 
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action.ToString());
    request.ContentType = "application/xop+xml";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.ClientCertificates.Add(/* Retrieve X509Certificate Object*/);

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Aha, looks like another example of convention based programming. I despise convention based, as it's very unintuitive. Either you know what magical properties to add, or you don't.

I once spent a day banging my head against the desk trying to figure out why a controller I created in ASP.NET wasn't working, until I realized the class name -had- to end with "Controller" (as in MyClassController) or ASP.NET wouldn't recognize it.... even if it inherits from Controller.

Such a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in place of your current code to send the request.

```
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
{
    soapXml.Save(gz);
}
```

Edit: Might need to use "new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true)". Can't say for certain how that constructor parameter will affect the web request stream.

Comment: First, thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, using that with either true or false as the constructor parameter, resulted in the same error message output by the WebException.

Comment: Very odd.

I'll have to check the code I've written in the past.

Comment: See my response to what I had to do in order to overcome the error.  I also kept your suggestion in place and put a `CompressionMode.Decompress` on the `HttpWebResponse`.