# Malformed Reference Element

Tags: c#, x509certificate, xml-signature, irs

I am attempting to add References to my Security Header and am running into a fairly generic error:

> Malformed Reference Element

I have tried the following with similar results:

1. Referencing the element within the document by passing in the `ID` of the element as the `URI` of the `Reference` object.
2. Passing an `XmlElement` object to the `Reference` through the `LoadXml()` method.  I am retrieving the `XmlElement` reference by using the overloaded `GetIdElement` found on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099156/malformed-reference-element-when-adding-a-reference-based-on-an-id-attribute-w).

When I pass in an empty string as the `URI`, the `ComputeSignature()` method of the `SignedXml` works as expected.  However, I need to add up to 3 references to the Security Header.

**UPDATE #1**
Thanks to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/03/31/105137.aspx), I was able to create the simplified version from that and I believe what is causing my problem is the use of the `Namespace` attributes and prefixes.

**UPDATE #2**
It appears as though the Namespace declaration on the `Id` attribute of the `<Timestamp>` element is causing this error to occur.

**UPDATE #3**
I think I got this working.  See my answer post below.

**Working Sample:**
*Please note the `Id XAttribute` with the Namespace defined does not work; while the `Id XAttribute` without the Namespace defined does work.*

```
private void CreateSecurityAndTimestampXML(string fileName)
{
    TimestampID = "TS-E" + GUID.NewGuid();
    DateTime SecurityTimestampUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;

    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(wsse + "Security",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "wsse", wsse.NamespaceName),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "wsu", wsu.NamespaceName),
            new XElement(wsu + "Timestamp",
                // new XAttribute(wsu + "Id", TimestampID), // <-- Does Not Work
                new XAttribute("Id", TimestampID), // <-- Works
                new XElement(wsu + "Created", SecurityTimestampUTC.ToString(_timestampFormat)),
                new XElement(wsu + "Expires", SecurityTimestampUTC.AddMinutes(10).ToString(_timestampFormat))
            )
        )
    );

    using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
    {
        xdoc.WriteTo(tw);
    }
}

// Snippet
string[] elements = { TimestampID };

foreach (string s in elements)
{
    Reference reference = new Reference()
    {
        Uri = "#" + s
    };

    XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
    env.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = _includedPrefixList;
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    xSigned.AddReference(reference);
}

// Add Key Info Here.

// Compute the Signature.
xSigned.ComputeSignature();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like, at least for the time being, the answer to getting this working is as follows.

Instead of using the `SignedXml` class, create a new `SignedXmlWithId` object, using the class detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099156/malformed-reference-element-when-adding-a-reference-based-on-an-id-attribute-w).

```
// Create a new XML Document.
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

xdoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

// Load the passed XML File using its name.
xdoc.Load(new XmlTextReader(fileName));

// Create a SignedXml Object.
//SignedXml xSigned = new SignedXml(xdoc);
SignedXmlWithId xSigned = new SignedXmlWithId(xdoc); // Use this class instead of the SignedXml class above.

// Add the key to the SignedXml document.
xSigned.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;
xSigned.Signature.Id = SignatureID;
xSigned.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = 
        SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NWithCommentsTransformUrl;

//Initialize a variable to contain the ID of the Timestamp element.
string elementId = TimestampID;

Reference reference = new Reference()
{
    Uri = "#" + elementId
};

XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
env.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = _includedPrefixList;
reference.AddTransform(env);

xSigned.AddReference(reference);

// Add Key Information (omitted)

// Compute Signature
xSigned.ComputeSignature();
```

Comment: Which using do you used for SignedXmlWithId ?