# IRS 1094C-1095C Submission using C#

Tags: c#, irs

Iam strugling for submitting IRS 1094C Submission. The IRS status retrivel service works fine for me. i reffered jsill and fatherof wine codes during the development stage.We are now in a serious dedline stage. the error we are now facing is a Gzip compression error messsage. Jstill posted a complete solution in File dropper but now i cannot access those. can you please share it again, so that i can compare my code with it.Any sort of help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what most of us did to get the GZip Compression to work was followed [Microsoft's GZipEncoder sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138373(v=vs.90).aspx).

Steps on additional changes necessary are outlined in fatherOfWine answer under my initial question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36021040/5286901).  User jstill was also a great help in overall effort of this project.